# Google Firebase - List all item_names

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

It feels silly to ask a question like this but I really can't find a view by myself after clicking anywhere in the interface at least twice.

I switched my app from analytics to firebase and those events do reach the firebase backend.
I also can see the events from the last 30 minutes.

[image: events from last 30 minutes]

They are stored under select_content -> Parametername = item_name

But I do not find a view of way to select a wider period of time. Like show that same statistics over a longer period of time.

Do I have to set up a specific view? Or how can I get those results?

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact problem and finally found a way to do it (though using the Google Analytics site instead of Firebase- but still using the select_content event).

In Google Analytics you can create a custom dimension from item_name (I did this in All events->Manage Custom Definitions->Create custom dimensions) then create a custom analysis in Analysis hub: I started from Blank, then used the Exploration Technique, selected Bar Chart for Visualization, added item_name as the Breakdown and Event Count as the Value- this gives the total event count for each item_name over the selected time period.

If you change the Visualization to Line Chart, you can also see how the values change over larger time periods (Granularities: Hour, Day, Week, Month).
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PN1vI.png)